# Apache SSL config breaks HTTP

Tags: apache, ssl

I have installed an SSL certificate today, and it works perfectly, pages sought through https:// work fine.

I have put a redirect in my website.conf to redirect port 80 to https, but it is not working.

Also if I go to http://www.example.org (the root), it gets stuck in a redirect loop.
going to http://www.example.org/test.htm goes to the same url minus the last /. eg http://www.example.orgtest.htm/ (slash moves to end)

This is really busting my balls, i really hope you guys have some clues.

here is my .conf file

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName example.org
   Redirect permanent / https://www.example.org
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost _default_:443>

  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
  ServerAdmin richard@example.org
  ServerName  example.org
  ServerAlias www.example.org

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.org
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example.org/html

  # SSL settings
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/www_example_org.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/digicert/example.key
  SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/DigiCertCA.crt

  # Log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /var/www/example.org/log/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/example.org/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i worked it out after much tears, i was missing
ServerAlias www.example.org

for port 80, Thanks to Ben for the HSTS header though, i will def use that. cheers

Answer (score 1):

Your config looks fine for me. Maybe, you should append a `/` like this:  `Redirect permanent / https://www.example.org/`

Instead of using `Redirect permanent`, you could also use `mod_rewrite`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

For this to work, you must have installed the [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) module.

If you would like for force https, another approach is so set the [HSTS-Header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) in your Apache config. Then, a browser knows that your website is available with https and will automatically redirect all traffic to your https-address. You can set this header with the following command:

```
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload"
```

In general, I would recommend reviewing your SSL-config with [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/). If your config is fine, you should get an A+-Rating. I hope this helps.